# In Powershell, how to wait for parallel jobs to finish before proceeding?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Based on [How to execute a PowerShell function several times in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766174/how-to-execute-a-powershell-function-several-times-in-parallel), I'm able to do this, where I stop all running jobs, in parallel.

```
# Run this in parallel
$stopService {
  param($service)
  Stop-Service -Name $service.name -Force
}

$services = Get-Services | Where-Oject {$_.name -like "*XYX_*"}
Foreach($service in Sservices) {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $stopService -ArgumentList $service
}

$doSomethingElse
```

But how can I modify the code so all my parallel jobs finish first before I `$doSomethingElse`?. Kinda like a `join()` command?

Comment: Santiago's answer solves your problem well in PowerShell v2. Note that `Start-Job` uses parallelism based on _child processes_, which is both slow and resource-intensive. In later PowerShell versions, much faster _thread_-based parallelism via `Start-ThreadJob`, from the `ThreadJob` module, is available, especially in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, which ships with that module - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375).

Comment: Adding to mklement0's informative and helpful comment, if you're unable to install Modules due to company policies, etc; you can also use [Runspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture all the instances of [`PSRemotingJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) returned by `Start-Job` in a variable and then wait for them either using [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-7.2) or using [`Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$jobs = foreach($service in $services) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $stopService -ArgumentList $service
}

Receive-Job $jobs -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

There are other alternatives, such as the one displayed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70705153/15339544), using a loop and [`WaitHandle.WaitAny` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitany?view=net-6.0)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71918903/15339544) shows a similar, *more developed alternative*, using a function to wait for Jobs with progress and a optional **TimeOut** parameter.